# GCC with the -fomit-frame-pointer option

Tags: gcc, assembly

I'm using GCC with the `-fomit-frame-pointer` and `-O2` options. When I looked through the assembly code it generated,

```
push %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
```

at the start and `pop %ebp` at the end is removed. But some redundant subl/addl instructions to esp is left in - `subl $12, %esp` at the start and `addl $12, %esp` at the end.

How will I be able to remove them as some inline assembly will `jmp` to another function before `addl` is excecuted.

Comment: Jumping from one C function into another C function like you are talking about is not likely to work well.  Doing this is undefined by the C standard and not at all something which compiler developers try to make sure works. If it does work it will very likely break in a future version of the compiler. Compilers think that they own the stack, and don't work when you mess with it. GCC does have good decent tail call optimization, so if you study up on that you can probably achieve what you are trying to do efficiently.

Comment: Can you give us a minimal input code? The big question in my mind is "why do those `subl $12, %esp`" exist in the first place, as they don't seem linked to `-fomit-frame-pointer`. Might be alignment as cHao said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by giving a function prototype, then defining it manually like this:

```
void my_function();

asm (
    ".globl _my_function\n"
"_my_function:\n\t"
/* Assembler instructions go here */
);
```

Later I also wanted the function to be exported, so I added this at the end of the source file:

```
asm (
    ".section  .drectve\n\t"
    ".ascii \" -export:my_function\"\n"
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't want to remove those -- that's usually the code that allocates and deallocates your local variables.  If you remove those, your code will trample all over the return addresses and such.

The only safe way to get rid of them is not to use any local variables.  Even in macros.  And be really careful about inline functions, as they often have their own locals that'll get put in with yours.  You may want to consider explicitly disabling function inlining for that section of code, if you can.

If you're absolutely sure that the adds and subs aren't needed (and i mean really, really sure), on my machine GCC apaprently does some stack manipulation to keep the stack aligned at 16 byte boundaries.  You may be able to say "-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2", which will align to 4-byte boundaries -- which x86 processors like to do anyway, so no code is generated to realign it.  Works on my box with my GCC; `int main() { return 0; }` turned into

```
main: 
    xorl %eax, %eax
    ret
```

but the alignment code looked different to start with...so that may not be the problem for you.

Just so you're warned: optimization causes a lot of weird stuff like that to happen.  Be careful with hand-coded assembler language and optimized <insert-almost-any-language-here> code, especially when you're doing something as unstructured as a jump from the middle of one function into another.

Comment: I'm not using any local variables in that function so I can remove them just fine. It properly assemles and links without any errors if I remove them by hand.

Comment: Yes, but does it *run*?  The compiler doesn't generally insert code for the heck of it -- it usually knows what it's doing, so chances are there's a reason it reserved 18 bytes of stack space.  If that space isn't there, chances are any code that would use it will corrupt the stack instead.  Updated the answer a bit.

Comment: I looked through the code thoroughly and removing the subl/addl will not affect it in any way. And yes, it runs

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely sure that addl/subl is not needed. And it didn't work for me. Changing `-mpreferred-stack-boundary` to 2 replaced the `$12, %esp` with `$4, %esp` instead. Interesting... Or it might be because I'm using Windows

Comment: It could be.  I don't see why it'd want 4 extra bytes on Windows, but i've seen stranger things happen.  Just wondering, though:  is this a 64-bit machine you're compiling on, and/or perhaps a 64-bit version of gcc?

Comment: It's local variables and/or temporary value storage.  Just because you don't name local variables doesn't mean no stack space is allocated in a function.

Comment: The function is almost pure assembly.

Comment: The add/sub is generated to satisfy the implicit assumption that programs may be interrupted by external events whose processing uses the same stack, for example interrupt processing or signal handlers.

Answer (score 0):

> How will I be able to remove them as some inline assembly will jmp to another function before addl is executed.

This will corrupt your stack, that caller expects the stack pointer
to be corrected on function return. Does the other function return
by **ret** instruction? What exactly do you try to achieve? maybe there's another solution possible?

Please, show us the lines around the function call (in the caller) and your
entry/exit part of your function in question.

Comment: The stack will only be corrupted if the `subl` stays. Thats why I am trying to make gcc not add it in.